# SQLAlchemy add comment to every query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make SQLAlchemy add a comment to every single query that I'm submitting.

I know from the docs I can do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def prefix_inserts(insert, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_insert(insert.prefix_with("/* comment */"), **kw)
```

But I can't figure out how I can do that for every single query, no matter what type, without having to list each single one in the `compiles` decorator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use events. There is an example [in SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sql-execution-and-connection-events):

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_cursor_execute", retval=True)
def comment_sql_calls(conn, cursor, statement, parameters,
                                    context, executemany):
    statement = statement + " -- some comment"
    return statement, parameters
```