# SQLAlchemy: how to trace db queries back to the source code

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions

I'm debugging lots of "idle in transactions" queries in my database. I was able to trace some of them back to the source code and fix the runaway sessions, but for others I can't easily tell where the query originates in the source code to fix it.

I think would be possible if I started logging stacks for all of the queries like [here](https://gist.github.com/eshirazi/8d011f511a1531a69f6dc8d9e7ebc68d), but probably there's an easier way.

My query to find the long transactions look like this:

```
select query_start, application_name, state, query,*
from pg_stat_activity
and state != 'idle'
order by query_start
```

Comment: Not a complete solution, but at least a way to differentiate applications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685861/setting-application-name-on-postgres-sqlalchemy

Comment: Another possible way with SQL query comments:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162470/sqlalchemy-add-comment-to-every-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918589/add-contextual-comments-to-sqlalchemy-queries